# How get the value of {match.params.id} on react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

this is my code example but I do not know how to take the value and after use it

```js
class View extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      var id = {match.params.id}
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/View/:id" component={Child}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried following this exactly? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: yep, I actually have the same, but I want to take that value so I can refer to my database using that value

Answer (score 9):

This might help you. Just create constructor i.e `constructor(props) {}` and inside it declare the `id` as a `state` variable to the class. 
Pass the value of `match.params.id` to the `id` by using `id: this.props.match.params.id`.

Now u can access the state variable anywhere in your code and hope it solves your problem.

```
class View extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id : this.props.match.params.id
        }
    }
  componentDidMount() {
      var id = {this.state.id}
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/View/:id" component={Child}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
      )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way :

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function GetId() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);
    return (
        <div>
           your expected id : {id}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

{match.params.id} like variable.

this.id = this.props.match.params.id;

this.apartament = json.find((entry) => entry.id === this.id);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Route path=`/View/${id}` component={Child}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params

You component will be injected a prop `params` which you'll be able to get to like this:

```
  <div>
    <h2>{this.props.params.id}</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: I read the doc, but I still do not know how to use the {match.params.id} like variable :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, finally, this code worked.
It may be happening because you are following an older resource that is using an older version of react-router-dom version 5 whereas you are using version 6. In version 6 there were many breaking API changes. The Route components no longer use component or render props, the element prop that is passed a valid JSX literally replaced them. route props (history, location, and match) also no longer exist, the routed components must use the React hooks to access them now.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const {product,loading,error} = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);

  useEffect (()=>{
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id))
  },[dispatch,id])
  return (
    <Fragment>
        <div className="ProductDetails">
        <div>
             <Crousel>
              {product.images && product.images.map((item, i) => (
                <img className='CrouselImage'
                key={item.url}
                src={item.url}
                alt={`${i} side`} />
              ))}
            </Crousel> 
          </div>
          
        </div>
        


    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Replace all your {match.params.id} with just id It should work fine.